# Unable To Change Font With CSS In People Search Core Results

Tags: css, people-search

So I made a custom People Search that displays user's information in a table view. Now I need to be able to customize the font of all that user information so that it can be printed and read easily.

I identified the correct class id and put together a css file that i know is working (tested it by hiding the web part with @media Print), but the font never changes from the default....

***How can I change it?***

The css file is being called from a Content Editor web part on the page btw.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you referencing?

Answer (score 1):

I was only referencing the ID of the web part itself, when what I needed to do was reference both the web part ID and the child elements of that web part ID that i wanted to change.

So when I was doing this:

```
@media Print
{
 #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ8
 {
  color:black !important;
  font-size:12pt;
  font-weight:bold
 }
}
```

I actually needed to be doing this:

```
@media Print
{
 #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ8 .ms-vb2, 
 #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ8 .ms-vb-user a, 
 #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ8 .ms-vb-title a
 {
 color:black !important;
 font-size:12pt;
 font-weight:bold
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change a SharePoint class like `ms-whatever` add at the en of the definition of that class `!important`. For example:

```
.ms-whatever{color: #FF0000 !important}
```